# При парсинге на python3 через beautifulsoup ошибка 400 bad request что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Парсил интернет магазин с авторизацией и через BeautifulSoup, но стабильно после 226 запроса каждый второй запрос выдает ошибку 400 bad request, что делать?

Comment: У вашего парсера есть задержки между запросами? А то мб вы их досите, а они вас блочат

Comment: Нет, сейчас попробую поставить

Comment: Не помогает, поставил задержки, все также после 226 запроса ошибка

Comment: 1) Поставить большИе задержки 2) Ловить проблему с 4xx и сделать огроменные задержки. А так, посмотреть что приходит в ответе, мб он капчу хотел и не получил или ругается, что много запросов. Или 226 запрос какой-то странный (я хз, что вы там шлете, мб разные запросы, а не один и тот же)

Comment: @gil9red Ха. Вот у меня было смешно. Я парсил страничку нашего ru.SO с очередью, чтоб мне было оповещение, когда проверять и забыл задержку. Меня забанило на чуть-чуть ;D

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, :D А я давно делал [сбор меток не имеющих описаний](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/Grab/empty_tags_stackoverflow.py#L20), чтобы самому заполнить -- по-моему я за каким-то знаком охотился :)

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема в том, что сайт думает, якобы вы робот из-за того, что у вас юзер-агент типа `python/requests`, то попробуйте использовать пакет `fake_useragent`.

Установка: `pip install fake-useragent`.

Применение:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
    
url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
    
# данная строчка возвращает рандомный юзер-агент
user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
headers = dict(user_agent=user_agent)
    
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```